# Rundeck PSRP Plug-in

Tags: rundeck

I am in need of a PSRP plug-in for Rundeck. Does anything like that exist? I am needing to connect to an AWS EC2 instance that goes through a bastion and has to be PSRP. I have tried everything combination of Over-There WINRM and the built-in WINRM to see if I could trick it into using PSRP, but to no avail. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, that PSRP plugin doesn't exist (at least not officially), maybe a good idea is to create a custom one based on [this](https://pypi.org/project/pypsrp/) In the same way of the [rundeck-pywinrim](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin) plugin is based on [this](https://pypi.org/project/pywinrm/). Here you can check the [guidelines](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/01-plugin-development.html) to develop a custom plugin.